# SQL Server Insert Command Error

Tags: sql-server, insert, exists

```
INSERT INTO BORCODEME 
  ( BORCODEME.IslemTarihi, BORCODEME.IslemAciklamasi,BORCODEME.IslemTutari) 
VALUES( 
  (SELECT BORCLAR.BorcTarih,BORCLAR.BorcAciklama,BORCLAR.BorcTutari FROM BORCLAR WHERE BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=6),
  (SELECT ODEMELER.OdemeTarihi,ODEMELER.OdemeAciklama,ODEMELER.OdemeTutar FROM ODEMELER WHERE ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID=6)
  )
```

My SQL command is this, and I have these errors;

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>   Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>   Msg 109, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Comment: You are selecting multiple columns in each sub-select that is supposed to supply the value for a **single** column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're really looking for - are you trying to insert the three columns from the two tables? Then write your `INSERT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO BORCODEME(IslemTarihi, IslemAciklamasi, IslemTutari) 
   SELECT 
       BORCLAR.BorcTarih, BORCLAR.BorcAciklama, BORCLAR.BorcTutari 
   FROM 
       BORCLAR 
   WHERE 
       BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID = 6 

   UNION

   SELECT 
       ODEMELER.OdemeTarihi, ODEMELER.OdemeAciklama, ODEMELER.OdemeTutar 
   FROM 
       ODEMELER 
   WHERE 
       ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID = 6
```

So this will insert the three values from `BORCLAR` and another row with the three values from `ODEMELER`.

If that's **not** what you want, then you need to **explain in more detail** what you really want instead.....

In general, you can ***either*** use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (List-of-Columns)
VALUES (List-of-atomic-values)
```

***or*** if you cannot provide atomic values (literals or T-SQL variables), then you can use

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (List-of-Columns)
   SELECT list-of-columns
   FROM dbo.SourceTable
```

(*but you cannot mix - you cannot have `VALUES` and then use `SELECT` inside of it*)

In both cases, the **number of columns** in the `INSERT` statement ***must match exactly*** with the number of atomic values provided in `VALUES` or the number of columns selected by the `SELECT` statement